# what is the use of {} in awk command in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, command-line, command

I ran below command on Linux terminal, it works, just interested in knowing how {} works?
example :-

```
who | awk '{ if($1 == "name") {print}}'
```

Comment: if anyone can tell what {} does in general , it will be good too

Comment: Welcome to SO, you could read this great link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for SO where you could find it whats the use of `{...}`. You could go through it and share with us your learning/queries too cheers.

Comment: What does `{}` do in whatever language you're familiar with? That's what it does in awk too, it contains a block of code to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs in awk are composed of statements of the form:

pattern { action }

so the stuff in the {} is an action to be carried out, when filtering the text that awk is processing

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html for a full guide to the GNU version of awk that is found on most Linux systems